# how to get rid of a past fake experience from my resume when I apply for a new company

Tags: work-experience, india, relieving-letter

My B-tech was from 2004-08 but I got some back-papers, so I passed out in 2009. Then I worked as logistic supervisor in a construction company from 2009 to 2010 (this job was not relevant to my engineering). I left the job with out any intimation as I had a bitter quarrel with the manager, so don't have a relieving letter but have the joining letter with me and payslips too.
Then I came to HYD and tookup some IT course and got a job in company XYZ in 2012 where I am currently working.

Problem is: I had faked around 1.6 yrs

TOTAL EXP shown in Current company: 1 yr(supervisor)+1.3 yr(fake)+2.8 yr(true IT experience in my current XYZ company).

Now I am planning to change my company after I get a 3 yrs of proper experience in my current company.

1- Can I remove my 1.3 yrs fake experience and proceed with my relevant experience only? Please suggest

2- Do I need to show my irrelevant supervisor experience while applying for new company ? (I am asking this point bcoz I cannot produce my relieving date & letter and that to its a non-IT experience).

Please help me with your suggestions..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with Bangladeshi laws and this question might seem stupid, but here goes: Is there a reason why you cannot just omit the 1.3 year "fake" experience?

Comment: I do not understand what 'I had faked' means. What actually happened? What is the 'fake'? Please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/34540/edit) and while you're at it, try to make you question easier to read - e.g use bullet points.

Answer (score 4):

Companies do not, in general, compare resumes, with your prior or future employers.  Which means that when you apply for a new position, you are starting fresh. If you were applying for a job which required a security clearance, this might come up in the background check, but in the normal course of business, companies that you are applying with verify what you tell them, they don't independently research your job history.

That said, the more you lie, the better your chances of getting caught and it getting around -- I wouldn't recommend making up any more fake job history.

Answer (score 1):

What was your original degree ? What is this HYD ? I'll assume that you had a non-IT or non-CS degree.

Its better to remove fake experience, especially when you have 3 years of genuine experience. If you are applying for jobs that need 5+ years of experience, then you need to rethink your strategy for job hunting. Why not apply for 3 years or 4 years job instead ? For 4 years job application, you 
can say that you have only 3, but have strong knowledge which you can prove 
in an interview. Some companies will give a chance to cases like these.

Companies only care if the person has the ability to get their work done properly. If you are a crappy developer with 5 years of experience (I know some), then no amount of years you add will do much good. So, see if you fit the job description well.

When they ask you about the non-it exp, tell them that you were learning IT during that time so that you could switch. There are many people who joined IT,
but had a non-IT bachelors degree. So, you are not alone.

If you have a CS/IT degree, then you can tell them that you were desperate for a job and the "back papers" or failure prevented you from getting a CS job. But, you learned along the way.

If you be honest now, you will sleep better and feel better. Otherwise, two years down the line you will ask this same question again or maybe sooner, you will ask - I got caught. I was not expecting it. They put me on some common blacklist shared by multiple companies. What do I do ?

Comment: HYD may be Hyderabad.